# sharepoint 2010 insert video to post of blog

Tags: video, sharepoint-2010

i'd like to insert video to the post of sharepoint 2010 site. This site made on "blog" template. In the ribbon button video and audio isn't active. Features "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" of site collection and feature "SharePoint Server Publishing" of site is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert video or audio is not supported with Blog posts in 2010.  I used this article to create my own ribbon button that inserts a blog video tag and then converts it client side when viewing the post.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2009/12/11/video-blogging-with-javascript-and-the-media-web-part.aspx

However, want to figure out how to replace the existing Video and Audio ribbon button, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: thanks) i'm find this link yestarday. it have a lot of mistakes, but idea is very helpfull